# How to remove input attribute from dropdown value onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have two form elements in my form, something like below.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
    <select class="input-medium"  name="state">
        <option value="0">-----------</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="suburb">Suburb:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, I need to remove `disabled` attribute from `input` only if user select an option from dropdown.

This is how I tried it:

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){
    var inp = $('#suburb').get(0);
    if(inp.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
        inp.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    else {
        inp.setAttribute('disabled' , 'disabled');
    }
});
```

But this is not working for me. Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: Can you use as inp.prop('disabled', false);

Comment: I just checked it, but it doesn't work. This is how I tried it  `if(inp.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
   inp.prop('disabled', false);
  }`

Comment: Added the working solution as answer, you need to change the html (just add an id) and change your script in order to use props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code a bit;

At first I add the id field for the combobox, then removed the get first one syntax in order to use jquery, and changed all attribute related values to prop.

```
<select class="input-medium" id="state"  name="state">
```

Also I tested, and this is working.

```
var inp = $('#suburb');
if($('#state').val() == '0') {
    inp.prop('disabled', true);    }
else {
    inp.prop('disabled', false);
}
```

One more update, we can write this one just in one line.

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){
    $('#suburb').prop('disabled', ($('#state').val() == '0'));
});
```

The working can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/h9vvacfq/8/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked it and not working properly. Here I created a demo to understand it properly. - http://jsfiddle.net/h9vvacfq/2/

Comment: I also changed the logic, previous one is just switching the value, and this one is checking the combobox value.

Comment: Now its not removing `disabled` at all.

Comment: also i have updated my answer to add click event wrapper.